Beginner Java question on importing bufferedwriter in module-info.java
I am pretty new to java and I am trying to import some classes into my Java project, particularly java.sql and java.io.FileWriter + java.io.BufferedWriter
In my module-info.java, I have added the lines:
module Mynewmodule {
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.io;
}

However, "requires java.io;" throws "java.io cannot be resolved to a module". Any idea on how I can import java.io to later use java.io.FileWriter and java.io.BufferedWriter?

java.io is not a module. It is a package, and it exists inside the java.base module which is the default one. Therefore, you don't need that line. You only need to import the relevant classes in your source file.

Hey thanks, this worked! I swear before I added this, I was getting cannot find type for  java.io.FileWriter + java.io.BufferedWriter, but maybe I made a mistake somewhere else. Anyways, thanks for the help and explanation.
